# The derivative of the reciprocal of squared L2 norm

Tags: derivatives, optimization, normed-spaces, least-squares

I want to solve part of an energy minimization problem like this:
\begin{align*}
\quad && 
\arg \min_{\textbf{X}} \sum_{i=1}^{I} \sum_{i' \in neighnors(i)} \frac{1}{ {\left\| (\textbf{x}^i - \textbf{x}^{i'}) - (\textbf{x}^i - \textbf{x}^{i'})^T\textbf{n}_{i'}\textbf{n}_{i'} \right\|}_{2}^{2} }
&& (1)
\end{align*}
where $\textbf{X}$ is the positions of point sets, $I$ is the number of points. $\textbf{x}^i$, $\textbf{x}^{i'}$ and $\textbf{n}_{i'}$ are $3\times1$ vectors.

To use a gradient decent method, I need to solve the derivative like this:
\begin{align*}
\quad && 
\frac{ \partial }{ \partial\textbf{x}^{i}} \left( \frac{1}{ {\left\| (\textbf{x}^i - \textbf{x}^{i'}) - (\textbf{x}^i - \textbf{x}^{i'})^T\textbf{n}_{i'}\textbf{n}_{i'} \right\|}_{2}^{2} }\right)
&& (2)&
\end{align*}

I have two main questions:

1.Suppose $g(\textbf{x}^i)={\left\| (\textbf{x}^i - \textbf{x}^{i'}) - (\textbf{x}^i - x^{i'})^T\textbf{n}_{i'}\textbf{n}_{i'} \right\|}_{2}^{2}$, is the chain rule still correct? In other words, is equation (3) correct?
\begin{align*}
\quad && 
\frac{\partial \frac{1}{g(\textbf{x}^i)}}{\partial\textbf{x}^{i}} 
 = \frac{\partial \frac{1}{g(\textbf{x}^i)}}{\partial g(\textbf{x}^i)} \bullet \frac{\partial g(\textbf{x}^i)}{\partial\textbf{x}^{i}}
&& (3)&
\end{align*}

2.How to solve this:
\begin{align*}
\quad && 
\frac{ \partial ((\textbf{x}^i - \textbf{x}^{i'})^T\textbf{n}_{i'}\textbf{n}_{i'}) }{\partial\textbf{x}^{i}} 
&& (4)&
\end{align*}

Comment: The reciprocal is not the same as the inverse. For example $f(x) = x^{2}$, the reciprocal is $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ but the inverse is $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{x}$. You wrote $g^{-1}$ which means the inverse of $g$ but you want to take the derivative of the reciprocal of $g$.

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve Thank you for your reminder. I've edited it.